# How to choose right error message logging strategy

Tags: c#, logging

Can someone tell me about what it the best practices for logging. I mean let's say we have following snippet:

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    _logger.LogError($"Invalid operation exception was throws. Message {ex.Message}, StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
}
```

So is it needed to include Stacktrace into message text. I'd care about that stacktrace can be too large. What is the best practices for logging error messages? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just log every error possible. It shouldn't happen very often, it is never enough of context every time you discover a bug. So just log it and throw it further.

Comment: "I'd care that the stacktrace can be too large". Why? It's only text. Have you got incredibly limited storage? Are you somehow unable to clear down your old logs? It's only my opinion but I'd say log as much info as you possibly can about an error...give yourself as many clues as you can.

Comment: LogError have an overload that accept an Exception and a message. So just call something like `_logger.LogError(ex, "My custom message");` And let the logging lib use what it need from the exception.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you're logging these to help you fix them. You (hopefully) aren't logging these purely to have a running record of "bad behavior". So even if some have **huge** stacks/messages, you'll be able to find and fix them easier, thus won't actually see these huge entries anymore. You shouldn't see extra information being logged as an inconvenience.